# Track user usage in my Visual Studio Extenssion

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions, usage-tracking

My goal is to get tracking information of how the users use my extension and some information about the users.

I've created an Visual Studio Extension in VS 2015, specifically an Tool window extension.

This is then packaged as an .vsix package.

I've tried Amazon's Mobile Analytics, using their javascript sdk, but ran into problems with executing their scripts in the extensions webbrowser component.

How do you handle tracking in an extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Azure Application Insight and used their .net SDK (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-insights/).

I was also looking into using Google, since they also had a nice .net SDK.
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/analytics/v3

Answer (score 0):

I have not used it, but take a look at PreEmptive Analytics (http://www.preemptive.com/pa), which works with .NET.